# findContours crash in Visual studio

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code going fine in ubuntu:

```
    img = imread("E:/object_recognition_c++/build/saved images/webcam_capture_2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file, comment if use camera
    Mat img_orginal = img;
    Mat src_gray, threshold_output;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    cvtColor(img, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(3, 3));
    int thresh = 85;
    threshold(src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY);  /// Detect edges using Threshold
    imshow("threshold_output", threshold_output);
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
```

I tried it in windows 7 on Visual Studio 2012 but at line:
`findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));`

It always crash with code:

> The thread 0x1bf0 has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x18c8 has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x153c has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x1990 has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x191c has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x18d4 has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x197c has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x1988 has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x1998 has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x1850 has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x19f0 has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x1994 has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x1980 has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The thread 0x19f8 has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>   The program '[7148] opencvtest.exe' has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).

Can anybody help me how I can solve it? Thank You!

Comment: is it the same on another windows machine? It could be a driver problem. Read here: https://www.quora.com/What-does-0xc0000417-or-1073740777-mean

Comment: Yes, this is same machine. Thank you for the answer I try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I think I was used wrong version of opencv. When I switched to 2.4.10 evrything is going fine.